# How do I compile TypeScript code into a single .js file, executable via "node mycode.js"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'd like to be able to do this without webpack, gulp, etc, just "tsc [args] mycode.ts". Is that even possible?

In my package.json, I have a build command like this:

```
    "build:mycode": "tsc --allowSyntheticDefaultImports --lib es2018 --lib dom -m amd -t es2018 --moduleResolution node --outFile ./mycode.js ./mycode.ts",
```

*(The reason all of the above config is done with `tsc` command line arguments, instead of being set up in `tsconfig.json`, is that I'm generating a build script that's apart from my main project, which does use `tsconfig.json`, webpack, etc.)*

I tried to use `-m commonjs`, but that's not allowed with `--outFile`, only `amd` or `system`.

The problem is that the code generated this way produces this error when invoked by `node`:

```
ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

I can't figure out how to define `define`. Is there an argument to the `node` command that will supply the necessary definition? Everything I've googled so far invokes extra tools I'd rather avoid if possible, or is targeted at a web browser rather than creating a command-line tool.

Note: Any solution which involves a `<scr` `ipt>` tag is NOT applicable.

Comment: [`deno bundle`](https://deno.land/manual@v1.10.1/tools/bundler) does this, and you can supply your own TSConfig as an argument

Comment: @jsejcksn, that, unfortunately, looks like it outputs single-file modules, not executables, and also looks web oriented.

Comment: In this case, your question is unclear. What do you mean by "single file" if not a bundle? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "web oriented". Deno simply bundles ECMAScript modules (optionally in IIFE format as an option). Any environment-related configuration (global variables like `window`, etc.) is up to your TSConfig.

Comment: By "web oriented", I see code being used in that documentation with `<script>` tags, and also bundled in such a way that nothing would execute automatically by including a bundle, it would just provide definitions that could be invoked. I want "node mycode.js" to immediately execute code, not just return me a function that I could call to execute that code.

Comment: I now understand your concerns. I think it's a good time to research ES modules.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compile my TypeScript code for Node.js to one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019087/how-do-i-compile-my-typescript-code-for-node-js-to-one-file)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to concatenate CommonJS modules to a single file using `tsc`'s `--outFile` parameter. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7252 for a discussion.

You will need to use a bundler (e.g. webpack) in order to achieve your goal.

---

Original answer:

When compiling a single file using `tsc`, the `--outFile` argument is not needed. Also, the `--lib` option accepts either one arg, or a (comma-separated) list. Here's a modified version of your example:

```sh
tsc \
  --allowSyntheticDefaultImports \
  --lib es2018,dom \
  --module commonjs \
  --target es2018 \
  --moduleResolution node \
  ./script.ts
```

This will not bundle your script, but merely transpile it to JavaScript. It will still rely on any external imports.

Comment: I had already tried that. The file imports two other files of mine, and without `--outFile`, I end up with three generated .js files, not just one.

Comment: @kshetline You haven't shared any details/requirements about your project, but CLI scripting is exactly what Deno addresses, so it could be a great fit for your use case. Here's an example from the manual: https://deno.land/manual@v1.10.1/examples/unix_cat

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple script that I made. It should work well for your use case

```
#!/bin/sh

SRCDIR=src
OUTDIR=build
pre_clean(){
    if [ -f build/index.js ];
    then
        rm build/index.js
    fi
}

pre_clean
mkdir -p tmp
mkdir -p $OUTDIR


tsc $SRCDIR/*.ts --outDir tmp

cd tmp

for file in *.js
do
    echo "// $file " >> ../$OUTDIR/index.js
    echo "" >> ../$OUTDIR/index.js
    cat $file >> ../$OUTDIR/index.js
    # sed 1,2d $file >> ../$OUTDIR/index.js
    echo "" >> ../$OUTDIR/index.js
done

# Cleanup
cd ..
rm -r tmp

# Add package.json
sed s:build/index.js:index.js:g package.json > build/package.json
cp package-lock.json build

true
```